# Disable consecutive space in textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to disable consecutive multiple spaces in asp.net textbox using jQuery.

The textbox should not accept something like

```
Hello    World

 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#txtFeedDesc').keydown(function (e) {
                if (e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                else {
                    var key = e.keyCode;
                    var name = document.getElementById('<%=txtFeedDesc.ClientID %>').value;
                    if (!((key == 8) || (key == 32) || (key == 42) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 65 && key <= 90) || (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 96 && key <= 105))) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (name.length < 50 || key == 8) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

This is the text box that accepts alphanumeric characters. I dnt want two consecutive spaces

Comment: do you mean you dont need white spaces??

Comment: @user2124167 you can do this easily with `RegularExpressionValidator`.

Comment: your "Hello World" do not have multiple spaces, I can see only one space over there

Comment: at client side, you must track the textbox's input length and take the input with `trim`.

Comment: paste ur designer code so we can form answer for you

Comment: ^[^\s+]*$ you can try this regulare expression...

Comment: @Rex i need the keyboard not to accept two consecutive spaces

Comment: @px5x2 : how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

solution using jquery and javascript

```
   var re = new RegExp("[ ]{2,}");
  if (("Hello   world").match(re)) 
  {
    alert("multiple space found in the string");
  } else 
  {
    alert("string is ok");
  }
```

[Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kcjrd/)

Comment: I want it using jquery

Comment: @user2124167 - you can use requglar expression as i suggest that will do your work

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RegularExpresisonValidator` and `ValidationExpression` can be like following

```
"""^              # Start of string
    (?![ ])       # Assert no space at the start
    (?!.*[ ]{2})  # Assert no two spaces in the middle
    (?!.*[ ]$)    # Assert no space at the end
    [A-Z. ]{8,20} # Match 8-20 ASCII letters, dots or spaces
    $             # End of string"""
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function trim (s)
{    
    s.value =  s.value.replace (/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/,""); 
    s.value =  s.value.replace (/[ ]{2,}/gi,"");     
    s.value = s.value.replace (/\n +/,"\n");           
    return;
}
```

Textbox not allow the multiple space between two words